# example display tag with one column as drop down using spring MVC

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, tags

```
The following is i'm trying..ListwithMap is passing using spring mvc.
```

But unable to extract Map from the list. it displays empty.!

```
<display:table name="ListwithMap" >
------
------
<display:column sortable="false" titleKey="dropdown.name"  style="width: 15%">
    <select name="s" id="s" >
          <c:forEach items="${Map}" var="x">
                <c:out value="${x.key}"/>
            </c:forEach>
            </select>
</display:column>
</display:table>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the id attribute to have a reference to the current element of the list on which the display tag iterates:

```
<display:table name="ListwithMap" id="currentElement">
    <display:column sortable="false" titleKey="dropdown.name"  style="width: 15%">
        <select name="s" id="s" >
        <c:forEach items="${currentElement}" var="x">
            <c:out value="${x.key}"/>
        </c:forEach>
        </select>
    </display:column>
</display:table>
```

Note that attributes, like Java variables, conventionally start with a lower-case letter.